# Firebase Realtime Database order by score

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to figure out how to order users by their score through the url.

I tried using "https://[my database].firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="score" however it doesn't list them any different.[image: user scores]

My rules look like this:

```
"users":
      {
        ".indexOn": ["score"],
        ".read": true,
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase REST API returns a JSON object here, and the keys in a JSON object are by definition not ordered. From [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

And from the Firebase documentation on [ordering/filtering data with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering):

> **Filtered data is returned unordered**: When using the REST API, the filtered results are returned in an undefined order since JSON interpreters don't enforce any ordering. If the order of your data is important you should sort the results in your application after they are returned from Firebase.

So while you can use `orderBy` in calls to the REST API, it is only useful to subsequently filter data. If you want to have the results in a specific order, you will have to reorder them in your application code.